# RxJava calculation in parallel

Tags: java, rx-java

I am trying to demonstrate the performance of RxJava compared to sequential (what I assumed to be) blocking calculations.

I was looking at [this post](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.dk/2016/02/rxjava-maximizing-parallelization.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425832/rxjava-and-parallel-execution-of-observer-code). From experience, benchmarking using System.currentTimeMillis() and Thread.sleep() does not yield consistent results when dealing with calculations instead of I/O so I tried setting up a simple [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) benchmark instead.

My benchmark calculates two ints and adds them up:

```
public class MyBenchmark {

    private Worker workerSequential;
    private Worker workerParallel;

    private int semiIntenseCalculation(int i) {
        Double d = Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(i)))))))))))))))));
        return d.intValue() + i;
    }

    private int nonIntenseCalculation(int i) {
        Double d = Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.atan(Math.tan(Math.tan(Math.atan(i)))))));
        return d.intValue() + i;
    }


    private Observable<Object> intensiveObservable() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {

                int randomNumforSemi = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 101);
                Integer i =  semiIntenseCalculation(randomNumforSemi);
                int randomNumforNon = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 101);
                Integer j = nonIntenseCalculation(randomNumforNon);

                return i+j;
            }
        });
    };

    private Observable<Object> semiIntensiveObservable() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                int randomNumforSemi = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 101);
                return semiIntenseCalculation(randomNumforSemi);
            }
        });
    };

    private Observable<Object> nonIntensiveObservable() {
        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                int randomNumforNon = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 101);
                return nonIntenseCalculation(randomNumforNon);
            }
        });
    };

    public interface Worker {
        void work();
    }

    @Setup
    public void setup(final Blackhole bh) {

        workerSequential = new Worker() {

            @Override
            public void work() {


                Observable.just(intensiveObservable())
                  .subscribe(new Subscriber<Object>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable error) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Object arg) {
                        bh.consume(arg);

                    }
                });
            }
        };

        workerParallel = new Worker() {
            @Override
            public void work() {
                Observable.zip(semiIntensiveObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
                               nonIntensiveObservable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()),
                               new Func2<Object, Object, Object>() {

                    @Override
                    public Object call(Object semiIntensive, Object nonIntensive) {
                        return (Integer)semiIntensive + (Integer)nonIntensive;
                    }

                }).subscribe(bh::consume);
            }
        };

    }

    @Benchmark
    public void calculateSequential() {
        workerSequential.work();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void calculateParallel() {
        workerParallel.work();
    }
}
```

I am puzzled by the result:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:00:21

Benchmark                        Mode  Cnt      Score      Error  Units
MyBenchmark.calculateParallel    avgt    5  15602,176 ± 1663,650  ns/op
MyBenchmark.calculateSequential  avgt    5    288,128 ±    6,982  ns/op
```

Obviously I was expecting the parallel calculation to be quicker. Is RxJava only good for parallel I/O or why am I getting these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the benchmark wrong. You should be waiting for the parallel work to finish otherwise (via `blockingSubscribe`) you'll start quite a lot of them which adds significant GC overhead and inflates the internal queues of the executors as well.

[Here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/perf/java/io/reactivex/parallel/ParallelPerf.java) is the reference benchmark for measuring various parallel work. Note that dispatching work has overhead on its own and  unless you have 500+ cycles per work item in a parallel setting, you may not see any improvements in such fork-join type parallel workload.

Comment: Awesome! It _is_ the dispatching overhead and comparison to more conventional java implementations of multi-threading that interest me, and ParallelPerf.java is a great starting point!