# RxJava Observable Parallell or not

Tags: rx-java2

I am learning RxJava.

This is code

```
public void d(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Observable.range(1, 1000000).map(c -> c*c).subscribe();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(endTime - startTime);
    }
```

This code just calculates the square of no.
Is it doing it in parallel?

I mean is it sequentially iterating 1 , 2 ,3 etc and calculating square or is it using Parallel processing?

Comment: Observables are sequential by nature, going parallel requires splitting the flow. Looks like you should read some tutorials about RxJava first.

Comment: Can you provide the links to some good tutorial code wise

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425832/rxjava-and-parallel-execution-of-observer-code

Comment: Single Observable in sequential. Is it possible I create three different Observables and execute them in parallel and when all executes , I zip there result?

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to always read the documentation from the official docs before posting any question.

I would suggest that you start with [RxJava-Operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) page, as it contains tree to choose which operators suits your purpose.

Now, coming back to your question, to understand concurrency and parallelization, please check [RxJava-Schedulers](http://reactivex.io/documentation/scheduler.html#collapseRxJava%C2%A01%E2%80%A4x) page.