# Making parallel API calls using java rx.Observable

Tags: java, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-javafx

I have a `Set<Object>` and for each entry in the `Set` I have to make an API call passing that as a param. And I have to process each of those responses & populate another Map with some own logic

Sample sequential execution:

```
List<MyResponse> responses = newArrayList<>();
Set<StoreNode> nodes = // Assume we have a Set
nodes.forEach(storeNode -> responses.add(myAPI.myMethod(storeNode.getId()));
responses.forEach(response -> processResponse(response, myMap); // This is a common map & I have some custom logic to populate this map
```

How can I achieve the same using Observables? I wanna make those calls in parallel & populate my common map `myMap`

I came across map(), flatMap() & zip() but most of the examples I saw were simple ones that didn't make API calls & process their response.

Answer (score 2):

It depends which RxJava version you are using. If its older than 2.0.5, then you need to do `flatMap`, where you create another `Observable` and ensure things are pallel there. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35429084/2707179) on StackOverflow.

Otherwise, I recommend using `Flowable` and then you can use [`parallel()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#parallel--) operator that changes your `Flowable` to [`ParallelFlowable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/parallel/ParallelFlowable.html).

So you could do it like this:

```
Flowable.fromIterable(nodes)
        .parallel() // you can also specify number of rails here
        .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(node -> myAPI.myMethod(node.getId()))
        .sequential()
        .subscribe(
                response -> processResponse(response, myMap),
                error -> log(error)
        );
```

See [Parallel flows](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Parallel-flows) docs for more.