# How to parallelize network calls using RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java

```
final List<Order> orders = Observable
            .from(searchAttributes)
            .filter(searchAttribute-> !searchAttribute.isEmpty())
            .flatMap(searchAttribute-> Observable.just(networkCall(searchAttribute)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
            .toList()
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
```

I am using the following article to learn RxJava :
https://proandroiddev.com/understanding-rxjava-subscribeon-and-observeon-744b0c6a41ea

In the above code networkCall function should happen on a separate IO thread however the network call happens on the same IO thread basically sequentially. How do I parallelize the call using RxJava?

Answer (score 0):

With RxJava 2 can use `.parallel`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51000827/1292745):

```
Flowable<Integer> vals = Flowable.range(1, 10);

vals.parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(i -> intenseCalculation(i))
        .sequential()
        .subscribe(val -> System.out.println(val));
```

Comment: We are already using older RxJava because of couchbase hence cant use this however thats for the info.

Comment: With rxjava1 you have to do . subscribeOn inside the flatmap too. If you take a look at the answer I linked, this solution is proposed too